# onClick method called automatically react

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component named `<Filters />` which renders a component `<PriceFilter />`. The `<PriceFilter />` component renders a `<Filter />` component and some other JSX.

`<Filters />` component:

```
const Filters = ({ price, setPrice }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <PriceFilter price={price} setPrice={setPrice} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`<PriceFilter />` component:

```
const PriceFilter = ({price, setPrice}) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleShow = () => setShow(!show);

  return (
    <div>
      <Filter show={show} toggleShow={toggleShow}>
        Price
      </Filter>
      {show && (
        <FilterContainer>
          <div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$')}>
              <span>Inexpensive</span>
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$$')}>
              <span>$$</span>
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$$$')}>
              <span>$$$</span>
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$$$$')}>
              <span>$$$$</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </FilterContainer>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`<Filter />` component:

```
const Filter = ({children, show, toggleShow}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{children}</span>
      {show ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon onClick={toggleShow} /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon onClick={toggleShow} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Clicking on any of the options `(Inexpensive/$$/$$$/$$$$)` in the `<PriceFilter />` component not only sets the state to the value passed `('$'/'$$'/'$$$'/'$$$$')`, but it is also triggering the `toggleShow` function for some reason. Can someone please provide a solution to this so that the `toggleShow` function isn't called when clicking on the option.

Comment: try onClick={(e)=>toggleShow(e)}

Comment: Is price a state somewhere in higher components?

Comment: @ShreeCharan Doesn't work :/

Comment: @dileepnandanam Yes, it's a state in the parent component of `<Filtes />`

Comment: Hi I Tried the code replacing `FilterContainer ` , `KeyboardArrowUpIcon `, `KeyboardArrowDownIcon` with <div> tags, since I don't have the declarations, and It works!

Comment: @dileepnandanam That's weird :/. The `FilterContainer` is just for applying some styles and the other two are icons from material-ui.  It shouldn't make any difference in the functionality

Comment: I will post the code I have tried as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code works with minimal setup. See what is going wrong in higher level component Test where `Filters` is being rendered.

```
export const Test = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('inexpensive')
  return(
    <Filters price={price} setPrice={setPrice} />
  )
}

const Filters = ({ price, setPrice }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <PriceFilter price={price} setPrice={setPrice} />
    </div>
  );
};

const PriceFilter = ({price, setPrice}) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const toggleShow = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Filter show={show} toggleShow={toggleShow}>
        {price}
      </Filter>
      {show && (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$')}>
              <span>Inexpensive</span>
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$$')}>
              <span>$$</span>
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$$$')}>
              <span>$$$</span>
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => setPrice('$$$$')}>
              <span>$$$$</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Filter = ({children, show, toggleShow}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{children}</span>
      {show ? <div onClick={toggleShow}>up</div> : <div onClick={toggleShow}>down</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I also tried it in a different project and things are working fine >_<

Comment: It's working!! I didn't get why but there was a problem in the parent component. I had created a local component in the parent and rendered it there. I just extracted that local component in an independent component and it works now. Thank you so much for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

It's working!! I didn't get why but there was a problem in the parent component. I had created a local component in the parent and rendered it there. I just extracted that local component in an independent component and it works now.